# Line segments are always compact?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

A line segment from $x_0\in X$ to $x_1\in X$ is a subset of the vector space $X$ given by

$\{x_0+tx_1: \ t\in [0,1]\}\subseteq X$

I know that this result is true for finite-dimensional vector spaces (right?). Because closed balls of finite radius are compact and a line segment is a closed subset of $B(x_0,d(x_0,x_1))$.

But in infinite dimensional spaces we have that closed balls are not compact (right?). Hence this argument fails... but I think the result still holds because a line segment is a "1-dimensional set" (it is not a subspace) and hence an infinite sequence of point should have an accumulation point somewhere. Is this the way I should proceed to prove what I want? Or in what conditions the assertion above is true?

Thanks!!

Comment: maybe we should add completeness on $X$ ?

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: This is true so long as the map $t \mapsto x_0 + t x_1$ is continuous. This depends on the topology of $X$, which you didn't specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument by sequential compactness requires some more argumentation - you have to prove that your infinite dimensional space is sequentially compact and that this is equivalent to compactness. In metric spaces, these two are always equivalent, but there are infinite dimensional spaces that aren't metric. There are even non-Hausdorff vector topologies, so some care here is needed.

What I would do if I was you, is argue that your description above gives a homeomorphism between the abstract interval $[0,1]$ and this piece of your space. Then compactness follows for free from the ordinary proof that $[0,1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f:[0,1]\to X$ defined by $f(t)=x_0 + tx_1$ is continuous as the vector space operations are continuous.

The line segment is just $f[[0,1]]$ and thus compact as the continuous image of a compact space.

If $X$ is Hausdorff we can even easily prove that $f$, being also injective, is in fact a homeomorphism with the line segment.